# Highcharts gantt chart : Task progress Indicator

Tags: highcharts

Using Task Progress Indicator Highcharts in the dashboard. Output is not proper. Refer the below image

[image]

I don't know the output which i got is correct or not.

**Database entries**:

Project Name -> **P-2020-0009**

Task Name  -> **Feature 1.1.2** (6 days)

**Sub Task list:**

1. Business Logic ->**3days**
2. Dashboards -> **3 days**
3. Database Objects
4. Form
5. Functional Extensions
6. Process Flow
7. Reports
8. Settings ->**8 days**
9. User Interface -> **3 days**
10. Worklist

Total subtask days: **17 days**

**Subtask calculations**:
17/6*100 =283.33

**But in Highcharts series.data:**

**completed** property directly set a decimal value between 0 and 1.

I don't know how to show my overall sub-task under the Task with the **progress indicator**.

or

I don't know how to show each sub-task under the Task with the **progress indicator**.

Comment: Hi @jacksantho, Could you reproduce that problem in some online code editor? You can start from: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Ldpg450u/

Comment: please check this https://jsfiddle.net/sanlak/zatc2q1n/2/

Comment: Actual Start is 2019-10-18. But in gantt chart showing 2019-11-18. Default month get incremented. Same Actual end is 2020-03-13. But default a month get incremented and its showing 2020-04-13.

Comment: It looks that your calculations are wrong. If you want to mark six days as compleated, you should use 6/17 example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3pdqsxzv/

Comment: calculation i am using (sub task actual start-actual end)days/task planned 6 days *100.   It's not mean six days is completed. 6 days is the planned days but its extent to 17 days and still not yet gets completed. How to calculate ? Please give me a calculations

Comment: So do you expect that the result will be `283.33%` instead of `28333%` ?

Comment: yes and also i need to confirm that result 283.33% values is correct one as what i done ?

Comment: Yes, it looks correct. To calculate that you should only divide 17 by 6, example: https://jsfiddle.net/kus5gjL9/